# Javascript scroll animation

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll

I am developing an ecommerce website on wordpress with as much css as possible as I have minimal experience with `Javascript`. I came across this website though and was impressed by the 'soft scroll' animation, the only way I can describe it is the browser equivalent of soft closing kitchen drawers.

https://mouthwash.co/news/an-introduction-to-mouthwash

I noticed in the source code they are using `Javascript` and was wondering if anyone could shed some light on how they have achieved this scroll effect. I have included the following css in my stylesheet, however it's not quite the same.

```
html {scroll-behavior: smooth;}
```

Comment: Hope it will works for you : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scroll-behavior/

Comment: I'm not impressed at all by that annoyingly slow scrolling.

Comment: @StackSlave Personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the styles of the body element, you'll see that they're using `overflow: hidden;` which disables the native scroll of the browser.
Instead, on the `article-item copy media-content` element, they're using `translateY` to achieve the scroll effect.
This type of effects are achieved using **smooth scroll** javascript plugins.
The one I use is [this one](https://github.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar)

Comment: Thank you Muhammad. Do you know if there is a way to ease in/out at the top and bottom of the page?

Answer (score 0):

tympanus.net/Tutorials/SmoothScrollAnimations

Is exactly what I'm describing and has a tutorial if anyone else is interested.